# Not being able to launch exported 64bit product when exporting to multiple platforms

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have followed the current steps to export my product for multiple platforms (namely, following the steps in the [preferred way of doing multi-platform builds](https://wiki.eclipse.org/A_Brief_Overview_of_Building_at_Eclipse#Preferred_way_of_doing_multi-platform_builds)). However, when I export the product to multiple platforms (for the moment win32.x86 & win32.x86_64) only the x86 version starts correctly. The 64bit version throws the following error:

```
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (97).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError cannot be found by org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.111.0.v20180524-1156
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 51 more
```

I assume that it is caused by the x86_64 swt plugin not being loaded, however while org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86 plugin is included in the contents of the product definition, when trying to add the x86_64 plugin into the contents of my product, it doesn't appear on the plugin selection dialog (and of course is not already in the list of plugins). 
The only thing remotely related to a x86_64 plugin available is the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64, but including this and exporting again (unsurprisingly) returns the same error.

I've checked that the target platform has been updated with the software site from 4.8 files, only a few warnings appear.

[image]

How can I force the org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 plugin to appear in the available plugins to be selected in my product? I there any additional step to allow multiple platform export?

Answer (score 1):

when you input "Work With",you can not only "replace 4.8 with your version".you must browse this url,(my version is 4.13)

```
https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.13M1-201907111805/
```

and find "Eclipse p2 Repository",now you find true url to "Work With"

it is very importen that You must find the release notes for it.
like this

```
https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it to work. My target platform was corrupted somehow. Creating a new target platform and following the wiki steps worked this time.

The steps are:

```
Open Window/Preferences.
Find PDE/Target Platform
Select your (active) target platform
Click Edit
Click Add
Select "Software Site"
Click Next
In "Work With" type: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.8 (replace 4.8 with your version)
Check "Eclipse RCP Target Components"
Check "Equinox Target Components"
Uncheck "Include required software"
Check "Include all environments"
Press Finish
Press Finish
Press OK
```